# Польза от древнерусского словаря

Tags: общие-вопросы

Кто нибудь пользовался словарем [Срезневского И.И.](http://esperanso-kniga.com.ua/index.php/russkij/slovar-drevnerusskogo-yazyka-v-3-kh-tomakh-v-6-knigakh-detail), не могу найти отзывов, одни описания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно быть специалистом по древнерусскому языку - достаточно быть связанным с филологией, чтобы вспомнить, что И.И.Срезневский - это имя в русском языкознании, а его словарь - это крупный вклад в науку

Answer (score 0):

конкретно вряд ли кто тут скажет, здесь нет специалистов по древнерусскому. 
Попробуйте на специализированных ресурсах поспрашивать. 
Но из-за имени и за такую сумму я бы, конечно, купил, будь в том хоть малейшая мне нужда.